# State Imports After Documentation Comments (Eclipse Formatting)

Tags: java, eclipse, autoformatting

It has always bugged me when I hit Ctrl+Shift+F to have Eclipse format my code and it moves my imports above the documentation comments.

What I want:

```
/**@author
 * @version
 * @etc....
 */
import java.util.*;
```

What I'm getting (After formatting):

```
import java.util.*;
/**@author
 * @version
 * @etc....
 */
```

Is there an option in Eclipse to disable moving the imports from where they are stated, or something to put the first documentation comment to the top above the imports?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like this could be a solution to your problem. 
http://www.eclipseonetips.com/2013/10/15/disable-eclipse-formatting-for-certain-sections-of-code-only/

As I see it, you could just disable formatting before the imports and documentation - and enable it AFTER your imports and documentation.

Comment: That would work, but would end up taking more time to tag the specific area.